# MS Windows, virtual environment, manage.py "Couldn't import Django"

Tags: python, django

When running `manage.py runserver`, I get the following error:

"Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and " Import Error: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?"

My research (eg https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/aXF1j55hb2Q) says this is usually a problem with either not running a virtual environment, or not installing django with pip.  The questions I've find on StackOverflow receiving this error (eg [Django installation on MS Windows, manage.py "Couldn't import Django"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007351/django-installation-on-ms-windows-manage-py-couldnt-import-django)) have been resolved with one of those two fixes.

I installed django in my virtual environment, and am attempting to run manage.py within that virtual environment. Django was installed with pip3.  I cannot find any suggestions to troubleshoot this problem other than those two.  What's the next thing to try?

Comment: So you still have the same error, or you solved it?

Comment: you probably forgot to activate your virtualenv